# simple date format giving wrong month

Tags: java, date, jakarta-ee, simpledateformat

I was trying to convert date from yyyy-MM-dd format to yyyy-MM format, when I run the below code with the input "2012-10-22" it is giving me an output of 2012-JAN instead of 2012-OCT. any thoughts on where I am doing wrong?

```
  public static String dateFormatter(String presentDate)
     {
     String formattedDate = "";
     SimpleDateFormat tempFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
     SimpleDateFormat finalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MMM");

     try {
        Date currentFormat = tempFormat.parse(presentDate);
        formattedDate = finalFormat.format(currentFormat);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return formattedDate;
}
```

Comment: Case is very important for the SimpleDateFormat mask

Comment: As with all issues with `DateFormat`, consult the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) first. `Y` is *"Week year"*

Comment: FYI, this code uses troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the modern java.time classes.

Comment: Using java.time classes: `YearMonth.from( LocalDate.parse( "2012-10-22" ) ).format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MMM" , Locale.US ) )` ➢ `2012-Oct`  See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/EULBmC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first format to

```
SimpleDateFormat tempFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

as `DD` is the day in the year.  `22` is definitely in January

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SimpleDateFormat tempFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Instead of

```
SimpleDateFormat tempFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
```